# Manipulate a student in a group

Tags: java

This is a class Student

```
public class Etudiant {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String birthdate;

    public Etudiant(int id,String name,String birthdate){
        this.id=id;
        this.nom=name;
        this.birthdate=birthdate;
    }
    public  String getInfo(){
        return " "+ this.id+" "+this.name+" "+this.birthdate;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getbirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }
    public void setbirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate=birthdate;
    }
```

I wrote a class `Groupe` to manipulate the students ... 
but a workspace error showed up when I wrote my `main` method

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Groupe {
    ArrayList <Student> etud =  new ArrayList<Student>();
    private int id;
    private String formation;

    public Groupe(int id, String formation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.formation = formation;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFormation() {
        return formation;
    }

    public void setFormation(String formation) {
        this.formation = formation;
    }

    public void ajouterEtudiant (Student e){   // add a student
        Groupe g =new Groupe(this.id, this.formation); 
        g.etud.add(new Student(e.getId(), e.getName(), e.getbirthdate()));
    }
    public void supprimerEtudiant(Student e){  
        Groupe g =new Groupe(id, formation);
        if(!g.etud.isEmpty()){
            g.etud.remove(e);
        }else{
            System.out.println("list empty ");
        }
    }
    public void supprimerEtudiant(int id){ // delete a student using the id
        int i=0; boolean B =true;
        Groupe g = new Groupe(id, formation);
        while ( (i<g.etud.size())&&(B==true) &&(!g.etud.isEmpty())){
            if ((g.etud.get(i)).getId()==id){
                g.etud.remove(i);
                B=false;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void  rechercheEtudiantNom(String name){ // search for a student by `enter code here`//his name

        int i=0;
        Groupe g =new Groupe(this.id, this.formation);
        boolean B=true;
        while ((i<g.etud.size())&& (B==true)&&(!g.etud.isEmpty())){
            if(g.etud.get(i).getname()==name){
                B=false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (B) {
            System.out.println("student doesnt exist !");
        }else{
            System.out.println("student existe !");
        }
    }
    public void afficheTousEtudiant(){   // to show the list of students
        Groupe g = new Groupe(this.id, this.formation);
        for(int i = 0;i<g.etud.size()-1;i++){
            System.out.println(g.etud.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me where is the mistake in my methods.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i didnt find the error ..that why i asked .... when you write this two classes ..then in MAIN for exemple create a groupe then you add a student then you try to show the list by methode afficheTousEtudient() .... nothing showed

Comment: Post your MAIN class along with main method

Comment: Edit your post and add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ajouterEtudiant() and supprimerEtudiant() you create a new instance of Groupe, assign it to g and add/remove the student there. This 'g' is discarded after you leave the method. Instead use directly the member etud of your instance on which the method is called:

```
public void ajouterEtudiant (Student e){   // add a student
    etud.add(new Student(e.getId(), e.getName(), e.getbirthdate()));
}
```

BTW: The line

```
ArrayList <Student> etud =  new ArrayList<Student>();
```

is better written

```
List <Student> etud =  new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: The same applies to all your methods. You never want a new instance of your list, operate always on the one and only existing member of your Groupe instance.

Comment: yes i did it ...& i wrote this main                                                                 main {  Groupe g = new Groupe (1,"SI");                                       Student e=new Student (1,"mike","20-04-1990");
    g.ajouterEtudiant(e);
    g.afficheTousEtudiant();                       }                                               but nothing showed up!!?

Comment: If you have followed my advices it should print something